# Example of using Felix file install

Tags: file, installation, apache-felix, spring-dm

i have been looking on the internet for an example of using felix file install ... in particular i would like to know how to load this bundle ad how to feed it with the needed configuration files.

I would like to take this occasion to aske you othe information like:
How does Felix file install work in conjuction with spring DM (are there any problems?)?
Since i don`t have a fixed dir list to watch with Felix file install ... is there any way to tell him to watch multiple directories (for example a directory and all of its subdirectories)which are not know from the start?

I appreciate your help very much and i hope i was able to explain you my concerns as clearly as possible